# Azure Powershell over ExpressRoute

Tags: windows, powershell, azure

I am wondering if it's possible to use Azure Powershell cmdlets, like 'Login-AzureRMAccount' over an ExpressRoute, without internet connection.
In my opinion this should theoretically be possible, but i can't find anything about this on the internet.

Does anyone has experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: `ExpressRoute` What do you mean? `Azure ExpressRoute`? If yes, you could connect your remotely VM on `ExpressRoute`, then you could run PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: Yes i mean the dedicated ExpressRoute that's between our on-premise environment and Azure. What i want to do is run a RD Session Host autoscaling script to add RD Session Hosts in Azure when there is not enough capacity on-premise. This script needs to be run from the RD Connection Broker, that is on-premise. It contains commands like 'Start-AzureRmVM' which need to use 'Login-AzureRMAccount' as far as i know.

Comment: Hi Jonan, you azure VM could `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Azure PowerShell works on Internet, if you don't allow your VM access Internet, you could not logon Azure with `Login-AzureRMAccount`.

According to your scenario, I suggest you could use Public Peering. The Azure public peering path enables you to connect to all services hosted in Azure over their public IP addresses. More information please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-routing#public-ip-address-requirement) and this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-howto-routing-portal-resource-manager#azure-public-peering).

Notes: If you want Azure PowerShell IP, you could try to capture packets.

Comment: At the moment i can RDP to the private IP of my Azure VM. The Azure VM also doesn't have internet connection at the moment, i can't ping 8.8.8.8. Of course it's possible to add internet connection, but i'm trying to achieve this without internet connection. The problem is that the 'Login-AzureRMAccount' needs internet connection, and doesn't work directly over the ExpressRoute. Probably this is not possible and i just have to add internet connection on my on-premise RD Connection Broker to initiate the script.

Comment: Ok, that's clear, i will do this over the internet then. What do you mean with trusted links, SSL certificates? I can do something like that.

Comment: Hi, you could use Public Peering.

Comment: Mm i will look into that. For now i'll do this over internet for easyness. Thanks!